# How to create 100 files on windows folder with rdfc.exe?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to create 100 random files (each of 1 MB) . Found that rdfc.exe can be used for this purpose. I can create a single file with command

> ```
> c:\rdfc>rdfc.exe z:\test1.txt 1 MB
> Random Data File Creator v0.1.0.4 (2004/12/19)
> Copyright (C)2004 by Michael Berthold
> Visit http://www.bertel.de/software/rdfc
> 1.00 MB written to 'z:\test1.txt' in 0 sec. (ca. 0.00 MB/sec.)
> ```

However I need to create 100 files using this? Can anyone help with a powershell script of batch file to do this?

Comment: Should be a simple `FOR /L` command. `FOR /L %G IN (1,1,100) do rdfc.exe Z:\test%G.txt 1 MB`. This will work from the cmd prompt.  Double the percent signs if you are using it from a batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CW answer of Squashmans comment:

Using a `for /l` loop you can perform a loop n times by using the syntax

```
for /l %%g in (1,1,n) do <yourCommand>
```

So in your case this would evaluate to

```
for /l %%g in (1,1,100) do rdfc.exe Z:\test%%g.txt 1 MB
```

`%%g` contains the current number in this case between 1 and 100. For command-line use only, you have to use only one percentage signs in both places.
Note that you probably can prevent these messages by prepending the line `@echo off` to your script in case you are executing above with it.

Answer (score 1):

try Something like this

```
$Expath="PAth_Of_rdfc/rdfc.exe "
1..100 | %{. $Expath $("z:\test{0}.txt" -f $_) 1 MB}
```